# Machine Learning Predict Another Values

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning

I'm really new at ML. I trained my dataset then I save it with pickle. My trained dataset has text and value. I'm trying to get an estimate from my new dataset, which has only text.

However, when I try to predict new values with my trained data, I'm getting an error, which says

> ValueError: Number of features of the model must match the input. Model n_features is 17804 and input n_features is 24635

You can check my code below. What I have to do at this point ?

```py
    with open('trained.pickle', 'rb') as read_pickle:
        loaded=pickle.load(read_pickle)

    dataset2 = pandas.read_csv('/root/Desktop/predict.csv' , encoding='cp1252')
    X2_train=dataset2['text']
    train_tfIdf = vectorizer_tfidf.fit_transform(X2_train.values.astype('U'))
    x = loaded.predict(train_tfIdf)
    print(x)
```

Comment: you trained your model with `17084` input features, and now you try to predict something with `24635`features, this does not work. Imagen you are training soccer with 11 vs. 11 and then the game says you have to play 14 vs. 14, you would be also quite confused

Comment: @PV8 Thanks a lot for your comment but it's actually weird because I know that there is a lot of tools which are looking your text then giving a result like it's ham or spam. However , we know that they are use a lot of data to teach machine.

Answer (score 0):

[fit_transform](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.fit_transform) fits to the data and then transforms it, which you don't want to do while testing. It is like retraining the tfidf. So, for the purpose of prediction, I would suggest using the [transform](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html#sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.transform) method simply.